# Connecting to MS SQL Server on a remote desktop from Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database-connection, remote-server

I am connecting to a SQL Server hosted on a remote desktop using Windows server through VBA with this code:

```
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open Connection
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Data Source=192.168.1.xxx;"
objMyConn.Open
```

Currently trying to use python to connect to the same SQL Server database with this code:

```
import pyodbc
server_name='192.168.1.xxx'
db_name='databaseName'
username='sa'
password='xxxxx'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=server_name;'
                      'Database=db_name;' 
                      'UID=username;'
                      'PWD=password;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor=conn.cursor()
```

TRACEBACK:

```
File "x/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should omit argument `trusted_connection` since you are providing UID and PWD. `Trusted_connection` fills UID and PWD values with your current windows user values so it is probably reserved for a local connection within the host.
I belive connection string should look like this:

```
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=server_name;'
                      'Database=db_name;' 
                      'UID=username;'
                      'PWD=password;'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, I still get the same error as before.

Comment: If you are sure about the credientials you are passing maybe it really is a connection error. Have you tried connecting to the other machine in any other way?

Comment: I can connect after adding a DSN and connecting through the DSN: pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsnName;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx')

Comment: In documentation it is stated that "A DSN (or Data Source Name) allows you to define the ODBC driver, server, database, login credentials (possibly), and other connection attributes all in one place, so you don't have to provide them in your connection string.". If you can connect while using DSN it means some variables of your original connection string are typed wrong. Or maybe it could be the driver since you are not using the latest driver available.